# Scripting (bash currently) - check various process status on a cluster of other hosts quickly

Tags: bash, hadoop, ssh, scripting, cluster-computing

Have a slew of services that run as part of a hadoop stack; want a simple CLI script that checks the various processes and gives a simple output for end user.

There will be over 50 hosts; and around 10 services it will need to check on each host.

Currently written in bash; I like the output but the code is slllloooowww as it checks each process; 1 at a time via passwordless ssh and pgrep.

Looking for advice or hints on making this faster.

ie:

```
Hostname        | IP              | Ping    | SSH     | Zookeeper  | Namenode   | Datanode

localhost       | 127.0.0.1       | online  | online  | _          | _          | _
node1           | 172.30.50.150   | online  | online  | _          | _          | _
dn1             | 10.142.0.100    | online  | online  | online     | online     | online
```

sample code:

```
fun_datanode () {
zup=`ssh $1 "ps ax | grep -v grep | grep datanode | wc -l"`
  if [ $zup -gt 0 ]; then
    dn=online
  else
    dn="_"
  fi
}



#main


#main loop that reads host file
for host in `awk '/^[0-9]/ { print $1 }' /etc/hosts`

do

#ping
  fping -c1 -t10 -n $host > /dev/null 2>&1
  RETVAL=$?
  hname=`getent hosts $host | awk '{print $2 }'`

  if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then

    if ssh $host 'pgrep ssh' > /dev/null 2>&1; then
      ssh=online
      fun_zookeeper $host
      fun_namenode $host
      fun_datanode $host
    fi
    fun_print "$hname $host "online" $ssh $zoo $nn $dn"
    echo
  else
      fun_print $hname $host "${red}offline${norm}" "_" "_" "_" "_"
      echo
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

There are utilities like pdsh (parallel distributed shell) 
https://code.google.com/p/pdsh/wiki/UsingPDSH

This can be used to run process checks in parallel on many nodes.

Parallel SSH was archived (read-only) in Google Code. For more up-to-date releases see https://github.com/pkittenis/parallel-ssh .

Another option is Fabric:
http://www.fabfile.org/

Answer (score 1):

You should use Ganglia or Ambari to monitor large clusters. They are free and open source. They have monitoring as well as alerting capabilities based up on thresholds.

Comment: You're right, Cloudera Manager or Ambari might be a better option to monitor Hadoop clusters specifically.

Comment: Is there any CLI utils though?  most of these monitoring apps are GUI and web based with a extremely painful REST API for a simple task of checking processes status.

Amabari and CM in particular take over the enitre install and will no longer allow you to edit the config files directly and require all changes made through the web layer.

Comment: We use CM and so-o-o much more convenient than editing files manually. Monitoring comes with it too.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution without scope creeping into a major project;

Instead of going to the well each time for getting process status on node via SSH; grab the ps ax once on every node then assign to local variable.  Then interrogate the variable each time for current process status.

Instead of doing (amount of nodes X amount of services) = SSH connections; now it only does (amount of nodes) = SSH connections.

From there; I may background / fork each SSH...

```
fun_grabps () {
psout=`ssh $1 "ps ax"`
}

fun_zookeeper () {
zup=`echo $psout | grep -v grep | grep zoo | wc -l`
  if [ $zup -gt 0 ]; then
    zoo=online
  else
    zoo="_"
  fi
}
```